# Android - How to reopen an app few seconds after it is minimized by the home button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need my application (minimized by the home button) to be active again on the screen after 10 seconds.

The idea is to always keep the application on the screen. If the user needs to leave my app (by home button), the app will quickly return to the screen.

Is it possible to show an application minimized by the user programmatically?

Comment: What possible use could this have besides malware/adware?

Comment: A client needs an app where a group of users interact with the app (imagine as a bench of state deputies).
As it will be on android devices, peoples can be distracted by games, whatsapp, etc, and in that environment (which is a working environment) the only application required will be that voting application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you control the environment, Android has APIs for this use case:

https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode?hl=en

Comment: dude this's not a good practice to do that ! you're locking the whole phone (blocking system UI features), I suggest creating a broadcast receiver and when ever the app is exited and it starts to work in background reopen the app again.

Comment: Um ... dude ... if you control the environment and want to lock the device for a legitimate reason, the official API to achieve that specific task is the best practice.